# bootstrap - dropdown with free text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to display a dropdown list on an html page. I would like that the user could also add free text inside the combobox if he doesnt't find the value he wants. Is it possible and not too much complicated? I have bootstrap and jquery. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far please?

Comment: I know how to write a combo box, but no idea how to add free text.For this reason I am writing here. If I can't get a solution I'll look for a workaround (two separates combo and text widget)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. By definition a combo box already accepts input from the user.

Comment: Suppose the combobox have three values:choose, dog and cat.Every time he open the html page he may want to open the combobox select "choose" and write some free text on it.

Comment: As for select2 from the link you sent me I couldn't find the use case I was looking for.I'm doing some experiments with the others

Answer (score 12):

With a [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) that is pretty easy - no CSS/JavaScript required.

Here is a Bootstrap example:

```
<form role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" list="select-list-id"/>
   </div>
   <datalist id="select-list-id">
      <option value="What was your childhood nickname?"></option>
      <option value="In what city did you meet your spouse/significant other?"></option>
   </datalist>
</form>
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MartinThoma/rp2cnqgh/1/).

Comment: Nice, I guess the only downside here is that if your 'datalist' has some ids that relate to another table then you loose them. But - nice - for me that'll work.

Comment: This is straight HTML and has nothing to do with Bootstrap.

Comment: @gknicker Look at the class names.

Answer (score 3):

To get you started, here are two libraries that will help achieve what you want.

[Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) supports many features and allows the user to input text.

Another option is [Selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) but I haven't tried it out myself.

Finally there is [this project](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox) which also achieves your desired effect.